# Parse string to DateTime in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

I am trying to parse String formatted like "23.1.2020" to DateTime object, but nothing works for me. I tried to use some packages like intl or date_format, but none of these can do the job.

```
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.parse("12.04.2020");
formatDate(todayDate, [yyyy, '/', mm, '/', dd, ' ', hh, ':', nn, ':', ss, ' ', am])
```

Do you have any idea, how to parse this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, I found way how to do that:

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat format = DateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
print(format.parse(date));
```

Answer (score 9):

If you are absolutely sure that your date format will always be `"dd.MM.yyyy"` you could do this :

```dart
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.parse("12.04.2020".split('.').reversed.join());
```

This trick will format your date to `"yyyyMMdd"` format, which, according to [the docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html), is accepted by `DateTime.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try out this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy), it also runs on top of [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl), but makes it easier using [momentjs](https://momentjs.com) syntax. See below

```
var date = Jiffy.parse("12.04.2020", pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy").format("dd, Oct yy"); // 12, Apr 20
```

You can also do the following default formats

```
var date = Jiffy.parse("12.04.2020", pattern: "dd.MM.yyyy").yMMMMd; // April 12, 2020
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Fuction Convert date to string :

```
String dateTostring(DateTime datevalue)
{
String _stringdate ="";

_stringdate = datevalue.month.toString()+"."+datevalue.day.toString()+"."+datevalue.year.toString() ;


return _stringdate;
}
```

Then fuction convert string to date:

```
DateTime dateStringtodate(String stringdate)
{
DateTime _stringdate;

List<String> validadeSplit = stringdate.split('.');

if(validadeSplit.length > 1)
{
  int day = int.parse(validadeSplit[1].toString()));
  int month = int.parse(validadeSplit[0].toString());
  int year = int.parse(validadeSplit[2].toString());

  _stringdate = DateTime.utc(year, day, month);

}

return _stringdate;
}
```